# Angular UI Bootstrap Carousel Pager stops working after I visit other tabs and return back

Tags: angularjs, carousel, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have angular UI bootstrap's carousel directive implemented on my site. Everything is working fine and suddenly I noticed that whenever I browse to other sites, leaving my site open in one tab and come back to my site again, the pager and carousel controls stop working. It's strange but I have set my carousel to auto rotate and it also stops.

The carousel won't work until I refresh. First, I thought I had some bugs in my code, but when I tried their own slider from the https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel website, also shows the same behavior.

Any thoughts or fixes on this? 
For the code, please visit this link :
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel

And scroll down to the Carousel section and click Edit in Plunker.

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/5471) and is under investigation.